# How to receive multiple ChunkedFiles

Tags: netty

Im building a client/server upload application.
The client is going to send multiple large files to the server.

I already found the ChunkedInput classes like ChunkedFile to send only chunks of the file to the server.
The client only adds the ChunkedWriteHandler to the pipeline and then sends file after file (is this correct?)

```
//Client snippets
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
  ch.pipeline().addLast(new ChunkedWriteHandler());
}
public void send(Channel channel, List<File> files){
    for (Iterator<File> iterator = files.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        File file = iterator.next();
        channel.write(file.length());
        ChannelFuture cf = channel.writeAndFlush(new ChunkedFile(file));
        cf.await();
    }
```

But what exactly am i doing on the server side?
How can i realize the end of the first file? ChunkedFile is not sending filesize with its chunks right?
Maybe someone can post a code snippet for the server side? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well i found the solution by myself.

The problem seems to be the

`channel.write(file.length());`

I have to write a ChunkedInput to the channel.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
dos.writeLong(file.length());
dos.flush();
channel.write(new ChunkedStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())));
```